# Android Studio Fragment RoomListFragment not attached to Activity (start new activity in navigation drawer)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I have problem with open new activity from class RoomListFragment. I using navigation drawer.

This is my RoomListFragment.class

```
public class RoomListFragment extends Fragment {
private View root;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rooms, container, false);

    ListView listView = root.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    RoomListAdapter adapter = new RoomListAdapter(root.getContext(),mTitle,mDescription);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return root;
}

void startRoomEditManagerActivity(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, RoomEditManager.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

and my second class, where i have button with one i active function startRoomEditManagerActivity

```
   RoomListAdapter(Context roomListContext, String[] roomListName, String[] roomListDescription) {
    super(roomListContext, R.layout.row, R.id.testTextView1, roomListName);
    this.roomListName = roomListName;
    this.roomListDescription = roomListDescription;
    this.contextRoomList = roomListContext;
}
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editRoomButton.setText(roomListName[position]);

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), roomListName[position] +" id : " + String.valueOf(editRoomButton.getId()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            RoomListFragment roomlistFragment = new RoomListFragment();
            roomlistFragment.startRoomEditManagerActivity(contextRoomList);

        }
```

Thanks for help ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace onclick with

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editRoomButton.setText(roomListName[position]);

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), roomListName[position] +" id : " + String.valueOf(editRoomButton.getId()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Intent intent = new Intent(contextRoomList , RoomEditManager.class);
    contextRoomList.startActivity(intent);

        }
```

Then,in your roomlistFragment, your dont need the following code

```
void startRoomEditManagerActivity(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, RoomEditManager.class);
    contextRoomList.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: this.contextRoomList is a context = this is in adapter class. In RoomListFragment class i have     RoomListAdapter adapter = new RoomListAdapter(root.getContext(),mTitle,mDescription);

Comment: So, any idea? ;-;

Comment: is the answer not solving the problem?

Comment: No, when i replace onclick, i have error with startActibity(intent) : Cannot resolve method 'startActibity(android.content.Intent)'

Comment: I have solved that issue in the latest update. Plz check the latest solution

Comment: Still same error. If you want, i can give you full code on git

Comment: Yeah! It's working now
Really thanks for help with that ^^